# Drools - Parser error while using a Map

Tags: java, drools, mvel

I've written a simple Rule that prints the name of a Person when the Age is greater than 18.

**Following works:**

```
import java.util.Map;

rule "PrintNameWhenAgeWhenGreaterThan18"
 dialect "mvel"
 when
    $data : Map()
 then
    if ($data.age > 18) {
        System.out.println($data.name);
    }
end
```

**Following doesn't work. Why?**

```
import java.util.Map;

rule "PrintNameWhenAgeWhenGreaterThan18"
 dialect "mvel"
 when
    $data : Map()
    $data.age > 18
 then
    System.out.println($data.name);
end
```

**Error Messsage:**

```
[10,13]: [ERR 102] Line 10:13 mismatched input '>' in rule "PrintNameWhenAgeWhenGreaterThan18"
[0,0]: Parser returned a null Package
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse knowledge.
```

**Java code:**

```
final Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", "Joe");
data.put("age", new Integer(30));
kSession.insert(data);
kSession.fireAllRules();
```

I know that I should rather be creating and using a Person class. This is just an example where I am trying to figure out how to use Maps with MVEL dialect in Drools.

Drools Version: 6.3.0
MVEL Version: 2.2.6

Thanks!!

**Possible Solutions:**
Looks like I need to use the eval statement, while evaluating a boolean expression?

```
import java.util.Map;

rule "PrintNameWhenAgeWhenGreaterThan18"
 dialect "mvel"
 when
    $data : Map()
    eval($data.age > 18)
 then
    System.out.println($data.name);
end
```

Suggested by Shyam

```
import java.util.Map;

rule "PrintNameWhenAgeWhenGreaterThan18"
 dialect "mvel"
 when
    $data : Map(age > 18)
 then
    System.out.println($data.name);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try?

```
rule "PrintNameWhenAgeWhenGreaterThan18"
 dialect "mvel"
 when
    $data : Map( age > 18 )
 then
    System.out.println($data.name);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Shyam! Yes, I've already tried that and it works. My question was related to how to use the $data.age in the next statement.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. Is there a way to avoid using an eval if I want to actually check the age in the next statement?